# Defining colors for many css classes based on a gradient color scale

Tags: html, css, colors, gradient

I have a gradient color scale that I want to define a set of classes for.

To break it down I have a value that can span between **0** and **8.5** with a step of **0.25**. I have a total of **34** different colors (8.5/0.25 = 34) that I want to span within this gradient color scale. So I need to define 34 different classes each a tad more down the scale depending value that I have in my database. So if I find a value of 2.25 I want to get the color **29.4%** ((2.25 * 100 /) 8.5 = 29.4) within my gradient scale. How can I do this by using css classes?

[image]

My reason for doing this is to add color to icons that I place on my map. The values are speed and based on the speed I need to add a class to my icon on the map that contains a background (color) that matches the "value" of the speed?

I have tried googling for the past 30 minutes, but I have found my self unable to find anything that I can use.

If this seems quite intuitive I am willing to try other solutions that can assist me in achieving what I need.

If it is of any importance I am using `MapBox` as my map solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SCSS. In SCSS you can use variables and math.

Comment: I am seemingly unable to find any documentation on SCSS or tutorials or alike. If you could point me in the right direction by adding a link I would appreciate it ;)